Подскажите как двигаться дальше в изучении c++
Изучил основы, начал изучать теорию ооп, упражнения делаю из учебника, а как дальше в практике двигаться? Думаю stl изучать и пытаться самом реализовать думать как в проекте каком нибудь применить. Вы как ставили себе задачи на практику и что делали, спасибо за совет

https://i.sstatic.net/1KKzlVY3.png

Я пробовал как-то раз, но вернулся к чистому Си

Просто идти и делать то, что вы хотите научиться делать (игры, какие-то полезные программы...). Почему-то люди обычно делают все что угодно но только не это (всякий leetcode и прочее).
